# EditText is growing as text entered

Tags: java, android

I have an edittext that is 80% of the screen across and a button that should take the remaining 20%, but when text is entered into the box or removed the edittext grows and shrinks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:weightSum="100">

      <Button
         android:id="@+id/people_relationFilterB"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="20" />

      <EditText
         android:id="@+id/people_searchBoxET"
         android:text="Search Known"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="80" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <ListView
     android:id="@+id/people_listLV"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any Clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your issue is you are setting the layout width of the EditText as wrap_content.  I had this problem when I started Android development as well. You are essentially telling Android that you want your EditText to size itself to fit the text you entered.

The solution is to set the layout width as fill_parent and then if needed wrap a LinearLayout around it to contain the size.

Answer (score 15):

Try to set android:layout_width="0dp"

Comment: To clarify: This applies to the `Button` and `EditText` widgets, not the `LinearLayout`(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set EditText

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: while this may be a correct answer, it is not very helpful. Would you mind adding some explanation?