# EditText dont grow with content

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with an `EditText` in Android.
Cause its only for Debug purpose, the visibility of the Layout, the `EditText` is added, is at start gone.

So i receive infos from an `ServiceCall` and to find some possible errors, i display in this the string i got as response.

i tried multiple solutions, nothing worked.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chbDebug"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="2dp" 
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <someOtherCrazyShitsAndStuff />         

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tbDebug"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="someOtherCrazyShitsAndStuff"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

So i found to setup a min/max count of lines with `android:lines/maxLines` but nothing happened. Also tried to force it after filling with the text to increase the Linecount through some lines of code, but result was only the the content was deleted.

Some more ideas?

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636267/edittext-is-growing-as-text-entered

Comment: yes i found this post too, i had first a linearLayout

Comment: i think that the little android has a prob with ordering things under another, this resizing worked accedently in the early phase of my projekt...  to get a scrollpanel i wrapped the backround (ralativelayout) in an ScrollLayout  and sized the RL big so i had enough place to build my little gui. i throwed the Debugedittext at end there was it out of my placment range (layout_alignParentButtom) and wooow it worked, but it growed other the other elements of the gui...  now it has his place and dont to grow for me :(    damn u little android damn u!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your `edittext` in the `scrollview`.

Comment: this would be the worst solution, only as last possibility, cause in the layout are some more debug things and i dont want to set them all invi one by one, thats why i put them all at the layout so i get this done in one shot

Answer (score 0):

i also had the same problem once just try this..

Replace this

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

With this

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Willl work surely